# how can i print Map values by using key

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

you can see the result in the image

```
{lastName: kha , firstName: mu, email: m.tayyaba3@gmail.com}
```

I need only map values with displaying keys

I need this result in this form **kha mu m.tayyaba3@gmail.com**

```
void getData() async{
    //print(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
    setState(() async {
      dbref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('data').child(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
      dbsnapshot = await dbref.get();
     print(dbsnapshot.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final result = dbsnapshot.value.values.join(" ");
print(result); // kha mu m.tayyaba3@gmail.com
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: What is the output? I tried it and it worked

Comment: only error red line